# What is the equal key when Emulate Numpad is enabled?

Tags: node-editor, add-on, edit-mode

This maybe such a simple answer to a simple question (I apologize since I'm a beginner). Since my keyboard doesn't have a numpad, I've enable this option. However, this poses a problem as while I'm using the node wrangler addon, I can't use the align nodes shortcut (Shift + =). Any solutions on this?

Comment: Numpads don't have an Equal key, they have an Enter key. The equal key is usually next to the 'backspace', in an english keyboard.

Comment: You can also go to *User Preferences > Input* and customize most hotkeys in Blender, including some addons. Change it to something else that's available and suits your needs.

Comment: @MattFerndz - actually [standard mac keyboards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9E7r.jpg) have always had an equals key on the numpad, even all the [way back in the 80's](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1986-Apple-Early-Macintosh-Plus-Beige-M0110A-Keyboard-also-Mac-128K-512K-TESTED-/112473848802?hash=item1a2ff6bbe2:g:DXYAAOSwjvJZUv4e)